# Could not publish to Tomcat 7 server NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse

`Eclipse 4.4.2v2015024-1700`

I'm trying to launch a local Tomcat 7 server that's for an older project I haven't modified in a couple of years. I was able to get the server up and started this morning, then I made some code changes that required a newer version of a shared library, so I updated the relevant POM with the new version number. I shut the tomcat server down, then tried to restart it and it's been stuck in this perpetual error of

```
"Could not publish to the server.
java.lang.NullPointerException"
```

Things that I've tried:

- add/remove the module from the server
- Add a completely new server minus the module, then add it later
- restart Eclipse
- Clean all associated projects
- Update all maven dependencies

Any ideas?

Related log entry in `Workspace > .metadata > .log file`

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.server.core 4 0 2018-02-27 15:30:03.862
!MESSAGE Could not publish to the server.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.impl.WorkbenchComponentImpl.getFirstTaggedRootSource(WorkbenchComponentImpl.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.impl.WorkbenchComponentImpl.getDefaultSourceRoot(WorkbenchComponentImpl.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.resources.VirtualResource.getProjectRelativePaths(VirtualResource.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.resources.VirtualFile.getUnderlyingFiles(VirtualFile.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.resources.VirtualFile.getUnderlyingResources(VirtualFile.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.resources.VirtualResource.exists(VirtualResource.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.internal.modulecore.util.ManifestUtilities.getNonBinaryComponentManifest(ManifestUtilities.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.internal.modulecore.util.ManifestUtilities.getManifest(ManifestUtilities.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.internal.modulecore.util.ManifestUtilities.getManifestClasspath(ManifestUtilities.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getManifestClasspath(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.calculateManifestReferences(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.cacheManifestReferences(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getReferences(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getReferences(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getReferences(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.internal.modulecore.SingleRootUtil.hasConsumableReferences(SingleRootUtil.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.internal.modulecore.SingleRootUtil.validateSingleRoot(SingleRootUtil.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.internal.modulecore.SingleRootUtil.isSingleRoot(SingleRootUtil.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.internal.modulecore.SingleRootExportParticipant.canOptimize(SingleRootExportParticipant.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.canOptimize(FlatVirtualComponent.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.cacheResources(FlatVirtualComponent.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.fetchResources(FlatVirtualComponent.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.wst.web.internal.deployables.FlatComponentDeployable.members(FlatComponentDeployable.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.deployables.J2EEFlexProjDeployable.members(J2EEFlexProjDeployable.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ModulePublishInfo.fillCache(ModulePublishInfo.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ModulePublishInfo.getDelta(ModulePublishInfo.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ServerPublishInfo.getDelta(ServerPublishInfo.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.getPublishedResourceDelta(Server.java:1575)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.getPublishedResourceDelta(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatServerBehaviour.getPublishedResourceDelta(TomcatServerBehaviour.java:958)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.computeDelta(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:874)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:909)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3157)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: Can you try it on the current version of Eclipse?

Comment: I haven't been able to get the newest version of eclipse to run on this machine. It's an older x64 machine with several versions of java (6,7,8) on it. It's so odd that it just stopped working and creating a new workspace and importing the maven projects back in causes the same thing to happen.

Comment: It's an embedded tomcat server within Eclipse.

Comment: Does your project have any source folders on its Java Build Path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain why this didn't seem to work yesterday, but this resolved my problem:

1. Restore eclipse from a backup.
2. Create a new work space.
3. Import existing Maven Projects.
4. Add a local embedded Tomcat server and set the project as a module to it.
5. Start the server.

The only thing that I did differently from when I posted the question was #1. I can't help but think that the one of the eclipse components either in the work space or from the binaries somehow got corrupted yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I'll share my experience with the same error except I was launching a version 9 tomcat that had been working in version 8.

It turns out that my server.xml configuration had a problem in it. Even though the configuration had an error in it, it worked in version 8 of Tomcat but not in version 9. The error was that I changed the defaultHost value in the Engine section, but I didn't change the Host section name value so that the two would match.  The apache documentation says that it's an error it the defaultHost value doesn't match a Host with the same name.  Again, in version 8, the error was just ignored, but in version 9 I would get the NullPointer exception.  I corrected that issue, and things started working again.

I will say that I did a couple of other things, so I'll mention them in case they are also important.  I deleted the Server from eclipse.  I closed eclispe.  I deleted the tmp(?) files in the ".metadata/plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core.  I restarted eclipse and then added the Server definition for tomcat v9.0.  I then could start tomcat.  I no longer got the NullPointer exception. I'm pretty sure that the issue was related with my configuration issue, since I had tried all the other things that I mentioned without making the configuration change, and that didn't work.

In exploring this issue, I noticed others mentioning that you should check your configuration files. What may catch you off guard is that you might have a bad configuration that was overlooked in the previous version. Is anyone aware of any tools that you can use to validate your Tomcat configuration?  That would certain be helpful.

Comment: And one more observation.  I would only get the error when I tried to start Tomcat from eclipse (in either run or debug mode). Tomcat would start up with no errors if I invoked Tomcat from a command line or started it as a service.